# Google maps - how to save an instance of a created map into a global variable?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coffeescript, global-variables

I am fighting last hours with saving of newly create Google Maps instance into a variable.

Here's how I initialise the map:

**set_map.js.coffee**:

```
root = exports ? this

map = undefined
handle_map = undefined

initialize = (map, handle_map) ->
    myOptions =
      center: new google.maps.LatLng ...
      zoom: 3,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    map = new google.maps.Map $('.map')[0], myOptions
    root.handle_map = map

  $ ->
    initialize(map)

  #root.handle_map = 'H E L L O'
  console.log('handle:::map:' + handle_map)
```

and then when I try to load the map in a different file:
**application.js.erb**

```
console.log('handle_map: '+handle_map); // returns "undefined"
```

But when I save to the variable `handle_map` the text `H E L L O`, that's successfully passed and printed out in console.

Why I cannot pass the instance of newly created map?

Comment: Hi mate, did you find the answer for that problem?